# What's the wrong number in the series?

Tags: number-theory, pattern-recognition

The series are as follows:

$6, 18, 21, 60, 66, 198, 201$

I was able to identify one alternate series:

$\mathbf{6}, 18, \mathbf{21}, 60, \mathbf{66}, 198, \mathbf{201}$ as +1*3 that eliminates 4 numbers, what about the other 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its 60 for sure the series follow a pattern of $×3+3$ instead of $60$ it must have been $63$ for more clarification :$
 6×3=18; 
18+3=21;
21×3=63; 
63+3=66; 
66×3=198$ and so on.